# The day I'll die

Tags: riddle

```
Only a few know the day they'll end.
I'm among those and I can say
that in precisely 20 years my dear friend
I'll live my last day, and pass away.

I'm not unique, and 'cause of my announced chute
They already found a substitute.
I have to say he's really great,
So great he'll bury us all, and the planet.

I'm not bitter, I made my time
I'm 48 and still dating 
So will you read between the rhyme,
And find who I am, without waiting ?
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are the:

> **Signed 32-bit integer** used by computers to count the seconds that have elapsed since the epoch of 1-Jan-1970 (which makes you 48 years old now).

You're referring to the:

> [Year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) that will occur on 19-Jan-2038 as the date of your demise

Which is when:

> The signed 32-bit integer rolls over as it crosses 2^31 - 1 thereby becoming a negative number indicating a date in 1901.

Your substitute is the:

> 64-bit timestamp which will allow for dates that greatly exceed the age of the universe.

Nice one waiting for this particular date!

Comment: That’s what will happen in 20 years but that’s not the narrator

Comment: Amended the answer @frabjrew

Comment: I figured it out right away but didn't see the riddle until now. I'm hoping we can get more puzzles like these.